# How to round numpy values in savetxt?

Tags: python, numpy, formatting, rounding

I fail to format a numpy-array when saving with savetxt:

```
from numpy import *

a = loadtxt('frequenz.txt')
b = sum(a[0:10,1:4], 1)/3-20741
savetxt('solution.txt', b, fmt='%.2f', delimiter='\t', header='average')
```

There is an error displayed:

```
fh.write(asbytes(format % tuple(row) + newline))
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'format' referenced before assignment
```

When saving the values without fmt it works, but I want to have only 2 decimals:

```
from numpy import *

a = loadtxt('frequenz.txt')
b = sum(a[0:10,1:4], 1)/3-20741
savetxt('solution.txt', b, delimiter='\t', header='average')
```

solution.txt:

```
# average
3.666666666667879326e+00
6.666666666667879326e+00
9.333333333332120674e+00
1.300000000000000000e+01
1.533333333333212067e+01
1.833333333333212067e+01
2.133333333333212067e+01
2.466666666666787933e+01
2.766666666666787933e+01
3.066666666666787933e+01
```

frequenz.txt:

```
#0  20741   20741   20741
6   20745   20745   20744   20739   20739   20738
12  20748   20747   20748   20736   20736   20736
18  20750   20751   20750   20732   20733   20732
24  20754   20754   20754   20730   20730   20730
30  20756   20756   20757   20727   20727   20726   
36  20760   20759   20759   20723   20723   20724
42  20762   20762   20763   20721   20721   20720
48  20766   20766   20765   20718   20718   20718
54  20768   20769   20769   20715   20715   20714
60  20771   20772   20772   20712   20712   20712
```

Thank you for your help!
Martin

Comment: what version of numpy and python are you using? I use numpy often and most of time I use `np.savetxt` specifying the format and I don't remember any error like that

Comment: Your code works for me using numpy 1.7.1.

Comment: python version: 2.7.5, numpy version: 1.7.1

Comment: @Warren Weckesser Does the first code work for you as well? Are the numbers in your solution file rounded?

Comment: I should have said that the `savetxt` call worked for me.  I used `b = np.linspace(0, 1, 5)`.  The values in the file were formatted as expected.

Comment: Even `b = np.linspace(0, 1, 5)` does not work for me. Any idea?

Comment: There is a code path that can produce that error, but it should only occur if `fmt` is not a list, tuple or string.  For example, I get that error by giving `fmt=99`.

Comment: Looks like there's a problem with your `fmt` string. Can you show an example of what it is?

Comment: I'm completely confused. I always type the python code in my editor BBEdit and run it in terminal afterwards. This does not work and gives an error. Typing it into terminal directly works. Thank you for your efforts.

Comment: OK, I got it: my default head of a python document is `from __future__ import (print_function,
                        division,
                        unicode_literals,
                        absolute_import)` And `unicode_literals` make the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Another way to get the error, then, is to use `fmt=u'%.2f'`.  I'd actually consider that a bug--if not a bug, definitely an ugly wart.  By the way, it's perfectly acceptable on StackOverflow to answer your own question, so you might as well make your comment an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution: I always type the python code in the editor BBEdit and run it in terminal afterwards. This does not work and gives an error. Typing it into terminal directly is working fine. My default head of a python document is

```
from __future__ import (print_function, division, unicode_literals, absolute_import)
```

The error is caused by

```
unicode_literals
```

Maybe it helps others. Regards.